# Как сравнить пиксель с определенным цветом на Python

Tags: python

Хотел сделать бота для игры в динозаврика Google. По идее он должен брать пиксель по определенным координатам и сравнивать его с цветом RGB. Ну например пиксель по координатам x=500, y=500 и сравнивает если этот пиксель цвета 255, 255, 255 по RGB, то нажимает пробел.
Не могу понять как сравнивать пиксель с определенным цветом

Comment: Каким объектом представлен пиксель?

Comment: квадратный обладающий определённым цветом.

Comment: Каким объектом в языке?

Comment: Объект это тоже самое что и тип данных?

Comment: Практически да. Как вы пиксель в питоне задаёте? `pixel = Pixel(r,g,b)` => пиксель задаётся объектом класса `Pixel`

Comment: мое представление о коде другое
сначала я создаю переменную где находятся координаты этого пикселя с названием pixel. После идет цикл 

if pixel == цвету RGB:
    то PyAutoGUI нажимает пробел
если не совпадает повторяет цикл еще раз
и даже если совпадает тоже повторяет цикл

Comment: https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=rvmjZaCrAqM&

Comment: Укажите в вопросе код, который вы написали, и что не работает с помощью [кнопки править](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/1142315/edit)

Comment: `"квадратный обладающий определённым цветом"` - вы сделали мой день! :-D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот функция возвращает цвет пикселя по координатам X Y:

```
import ctypes


def pixel(x, y):
    hdc = ctypes.windll.user32.GetDC(0)
    color = ctypes.windll.gdi32.GetPixel(hdc, x, y)
    # color is in the format 0xbbggrr https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd183449(v=vs.85).aspx
    r = color % 256
    g = (color // 256) % 256
    b = color // (256 ** 2)
    ctypes.windll.user32.ReleaseDC(0, hdc)
    return (r, g, b)
```

Для того что бы стравинвать значения в Питоне используют оператор `==`. Он возвращает `True` (Истина) если значение слева = значению  справа и `False` в противном случае (значение слева не равно значению справа). Таким образом пишем ещё 1 фукнцию:

```
is_this_pixel_black(x, y):  
   return (255, 255, 255) == pixel(x, y)
```

Comment: Вместо название pixel лучше использовать `def get_RGB_color_pixel`